# Monitor Process and echo if taking too long

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I have a script that monitors a Process and display (flashes) "..Please Wait.." while the Process is in progress
Then returns "...Process complete" once the Process is done.
How can I terminate the monitoring and Output something like "Timeout" if The process is more than, say, 120 seconds.
 - without terminating the ongoing Example process

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
sleep 160 &  # Example process
pid=$!
echo 'Getting data\r\c'
sleep 2
while kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null
do
echo '...Please Wait..\r\c'
sleep 1
echo '                \r\c'
sleep 1
done
echo '...Process complete\r\c'
sleep 2
exit
```

Comment: Have you looked in to using the `wait` command?

Comment: `wait` is all-or-nothing; you block until the process completes, so you'd have to interrupt the `wait` call periodically to display any output. (I thought a later version of `bash` added a timeout option to `wait`, but I can't find a reference for it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone, I added another while loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
TIMEOUT=15
START_TIME=`date +%s`   # seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
END_TIME=$(( $START_TIME + $TIMEOUT ))
while
do
    sleep 60 &
    pid=$!
    echo 'Getting data\r\c'
    sleep 2
    while kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null
    do
       START_TIME=`date +%s`
       echo '...Please Wait..\r\c'
       sleep 1
       echo '                \r\c'
       sleep 1
       if [ `date +%s` -gt "$END_TIME" ]; then
         echo '...timeout\r\c'
         break 2
       fi
    done   
    echo '...Process complete\r\c'
    sleep 1
    break 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You should break the while loop in case of timeout.

```
...
TIMEOUT=120
START_TIME=`date +%s`   # seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
END_TIME=$(( $START_TIME + $TIMEOUT ))
...
while kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null; do
    #break if current timestamp is greater than precalculated END_TIME
    if [ `date +%s` -gt "$END_TIME" ]; then
        echo "Timeout"
        exit;
    fi
    ...
done
```

Optionally short-circuit evaluation could be used instead of if statement. Like this:

```
[ `date +%s` -gt "$END_TIME" ] && echo "Timeout" && exit
```

Comment: Thank you, If I break I get "...Process complete" echoed, which I dont want will like to echo only " Timeout".

Comment: Instead of calling `date` repeatedly, just reset the value of `SECONDS` to 0 before the loop, then compare its value to `TIMEOUT` inside the loop.

Comment: @szkj exit will terminate the ongoing process , which I dont want.

Comment: Thanks @szkj, I think I got it. I used your IF condition and added a second while loop.